# ANTLR4 + Python parsing from string instead of path

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am using ANTLR4 with Python and I am currently using the following code for parsing:

```
lexer = MyGrammarLexer(FileStream(path))
stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = MyGrammarParser(stream)
return parser.start().object
```

However, I would like to change this code to parse directly from a given string instead of a given path. Thus changing the first line to something similar to

```
lexer = MyGrammarLexer(a_given_string)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the sources of the [Python2](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/Python2/src/antlr4) and [Python3](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/Python3/src/antlr4) runtimes, I'd say use an `InputStream` instead:

```
lexer = MyGrammarLexer(InputStream(a_given_string))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.